# What is the easiest way to find where a native library is coming from?

Tags: android, react-native, android-ndk

The final apk consists of a bunch of .so files. What is the easiest way to find from which dependencies these .so files are coming?

Comment: Go to the dependency's git and search for .so files?  Or .c/.cpp files?  Why are you concerned about this?  Most of them are probably from react native itself, the Javascript engine it runs on is written in C or C++

Comment: I'm interested in finding out where are different libraries coming from to have a size pie chart per library.  Apparently not all of them are from react. I went through all aar files and matched all .so files inside them to the .so files inside the final apk. Maybe there is an easier way to do it.